# How can I get Angular routes from module to work?

Tags: angular

I have an app-component and a provider module in the application. I want to configure routing based on this provider module.

I tried having in app-routing.module.ts (the main app routing file) **both**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'provider',
        loadChildren: () => import('./provider/provider.module').then(m => m.ProviderModule)
      }
    ]
}
];
```

or

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'provider',
    loadChildren: () => import('./provider/provider.module').then(m => m.ProviderModule)
} 
];
```

and in provider-routing.module.ts I have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'rr',
  component: RComponent,
  data: {
    title: 'R',
    status: true
  }
}
];
```

RComponent just contains some dummy text.
The problem is that localhost/provider route is opening a default page and localhost/provider/rr is not being recognized as a route. Can anyone help me get this code working ? Thanks.

Comment: In your ProviderModule, did you import ProviderRouting?

Comment: That was it. Thanks

Comment: I put now as an answer, can you put it as right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import PorivderRouting in your ProviderModule. Now, Angular will recognize the second route.